# Can't deploy Keycloak using Kubernetes (AWS and local)

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I'm trying to deploy Keycloak in Kubernetes. Here there is my service and deploy:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:16.1.1
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
              value: "admin"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
              value: "admin"
            - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
              value: "true"
            - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL
              value: dns.DNS_PING
            - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES
              value: "dns_query=keycloak"
            - name: CACHE_OWNERS_COUNT
              value: "2"
            - name: CACHE_OWNERS_AUTH_SESSIONS_COUNT
              value: "2"
          ports:
            - name: jgroups
              containerPort: 7600
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: https
              containerPort: 8443
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /auth/realms/master
              port: 8080
```

If I make the deploy in a *local cluster* (the default docker-desktop cluster using MacOSX), the pod became ready but i can't reach the main /auth page.
I try also to deploy using AWS but I get this error:

```
'Readiness probe failed: Get http://XXXXXX/: dial tcp XXXXX: getsockopt: connection refused'.
```

I tried increasing initialDelay seconds but without result, maybe I entered too low value?

Could anyone help me solve the problem?

Also it would be helpful how I should import a configuration of realm.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak should be deployed as Statefulset, not as deployment.  there is a discussion on the this to avoid any issue in the future.

[Keycloak Deployment vs. Statefulset](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/11763)

Also, it should be backed by database for the persistent realm.

> Keycloak uses a relational database management system (RDBMS) to persist some metadata about realms, clients, users, and so on.

[Configuring the database - Server - Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html)

so I will suggest to go with helm-chart

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install my-release bitnami/keycloak
```

Comment: do you have more detailed tutorial?

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-kube

Comment: I already seen this guide during my tests, honestly i do not understand what i have to put in KEYCLOAK_HOST